# How To Share and Access the Linked List between the Two Threads

Tags: c

I need to design a system where there are two Threads T1 and T2 where T1 submits the results and T2 reads the results.

What is the most efficient way of defining a Data Structure that can be used to design such system ? There is no shared memory that can be accessed between the threads and there is a restriction of the usage of memcpy in case if we copy the result .

The result structure is defined as

```
typedef struct 
{
   UINT32 ot_id;
   BOOLEAN result;

} RESULT;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (Portable) C defines no way to do this. Are you on Windows, GNU/Linux or Unix, or something more exotic?

Comment: Your question is a bit confused. The data structure design and the mechanism for sharing that data between threads are orthogonal. And what do you mean by "There is no shared memory that can be accessed between the threads"? By definition memory is shared between all threads of the same process.

Comment: @kaylum: I *think* he means that his *assignment* does not allow him to exploit shared memory for his purposes.

Comment: Presuming you are talking about pthreads, then as long as your data is global, both threads will have full access. The trick comes in writing to the list from either thread. In that case, you need to employ a mutex lock on the thread writing and remove the mutex when the write operation is done.

Comment: T1 submits the results and T2 reads the results, so the results need to share between threads. In your case, you should use Producer/Consumer patter (use [condition variable](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables))

Comment: @VuongHoang: He already state that *he can't use shared memory*.

Comment: Without the use of shared memory, you must use some form of IPC (Inter-Process Communication) - file IO, pipes, sockets, etc. If you must use some form of IPC; then the data structures used by sender or receiver (if any) don't matter much.

Answer (score 1):

( **THIS ANSWER IS VALID AS LONG AS YOU ARE ON A UNIX/UNIX-LIKE PLATFORM!** )

Although by definition the existence of threads *implies* shared memory, you can go the weirdo way and use pipes instead.

The function `pipe()` is declared in `<unistd.h>`. It takes a `int[2]` as parameter, and returns an error code `int` (`0` is success, failure otherwise). If successful, the function creates two new file descriptors, one for reading and other for writing. Whenever you write in the write-only file descriptor, that data arrives at the read-only file descriptor! That mechanism is known as a *pipe*. If you try to read in the read-only file descriptor, but the data is still not there, the `read()` function will simply block (unless instructed to do otherwise by means of `fcntl()`).

For any `int fd[2]`, `pipe(fd)` sets `fd[0]` to the read end and `fd[1]` to the write end.

Now, what you can do is call `pipe` before spawning the second thread, and pass `fd[0]` as an argument to it, so it can read the data! Let's see an example (note, **no error checking**!)...

```
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct {
    UINT32  ot_id;
    BOOLEAN result;
} RESULT;

void secondThread(int readDescriptor) {
    RESULT result;
    read(readDescriptor, &result, sizeof(RESULT));

    // Do something with that...

    close(readDescriptor);
}

int main() {
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);

    spawnTheSecondHolyThread(secondThread, fd[0]);

    RESULT result;

    // Calculate the result...

    write(fd[1], &result, sizeof(result));
    close(fd[1]);

   joinTheSecondThread();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kemy. This is helpful. I tried to enque the results into a globally allocated linked list from Thread 1 , but when I tried to Deque the Results from Thread 2 , I am facing Segmentation Faults.

Comment: @user3555115: Hi! Can you please post your whole sources in [PasteBin](http://www.pastebin.com/) or something of the like for me to analyze your code? There are lots of things that can be wrong with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
> Use queue.
> 1. create the queue and call the method that will produce(submit) data to the queue.
> 2. create a new thread that will read the data from the queue.
> 3. use mutex or any else mechanism to protect the queue heads. Else you can go lock free queue implementation.
> 
> Let me know if you need any code.
```